# Dimension of vector space of complex numbers over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that over $\mathbb{R}$ the dimension is 2. Whats the difference if its over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Hint:  what is the cardinality of any finite dimensional vector space over a countable field?

Answer (score 0):

The dimension over $\mathbb{Q}$ is infinite. If it was finite, then we would have an isomorphism of $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces $\mathbb{C}\simeq \mathbb{Q}^n$ for some $n\geq 0$. In particular, $\mathbb{C}$ would be countable, which is not the case, since $\mathbb{R}$ is already not countable.

If you want an explicite infinite family of $\mathbb{Q}$-linearly independent complex numbers, you could take $(e^n)_{n\geq 0}$ (consequence of the fact that $e$ is transcendental over $\mathbb{Q}$), or $(\sqrt{p})_{p\in P}$, where $P$ is the set of prime numbers (difficult).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that the dimension over $ \mathbb Q$ is finite, say $n \in \mathbb N.$ Let $\{z_1,...,z_n\}$ be a basis. If $z \in \mathbb C$, then there are rational numbers $r_1,....,r_n$ such that

$$(*) \quad z=r_1z_1+...+r_nz_n.$$

Since $ \mathbb Q$ is countable, we see , by $(*)$, that $ \mathbb C$ is countable, a contradiction.